# Windows updates: Restart instead of the requested Shutdown?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, shutdown, updates, reboot

I often hibernate my laptop.  Sometimes, I see the Hibernate button turn yellow and show "Shutdown!", which means that there are important updates that will be installed.  I then initiate a lengthy shut down, then do other things as it slowly updates before shutting down.

My problem is that when I boot up, likely the next day, it takes a long time to finish the updates.  I don't go and do something else because there is something very specific that I need to do on the laptop, which caused me to boot it up.

What. A. Waste. Of. Time.

It would be much better if I could have the laptop boot up by itself after the initial down, complete the updates *before* I need to use it, then hibernate itself (or even shut down again).

To accomplish this, I wonder:

When the Hibernate button becomes a yellow "Shutdown!" button to indicate the need to update, is it just as good to Restart the computer so that it starts up by itself to complete the updates?

Is there any risk that the difference in process might prevent some updates?

At the moment, I am asking in the context of Windows 7, but I need to migrate to Windows 10 imminently.  Please respond in both contexts, if possible.  If not, please specify which context you're responding in.  Thanks.

Comment: *When the Hibernate button becomes a yellow "Shutdown!" button to indicate the need to update, is it just as good to Restart the computer so that it starts up by itself to complete the updates?* For Windows 7 - no. In such case shutdown is the only option. Reboot do NOT installs updates - the poweroff knob will be decorated with orange shield again...

Comment: I remember doing restart on Windows 7 for updating.

Comment: Perhaps it worked in the past.  This puts the answer as "Maybe sometimes".  It's enough to make me continue doing the Shutdown, as explicitly requested by the OS.  Thanks!  Anyone want to post this answer, or shall we wait for someone who has insight into the designed-for behaviour under the hood?